# Automatically generate mapping function for data with higher-kinded parameter

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, generic-programming, higher-kinded-types

Consider the data type

```
data Foo f = Foo {fooInt :: f Int, fooBool :: f Bool}
```

I would like a function `mapFoo :: (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Foo f -> Foo g`. My options:

- I could write it manually. This is mildly annoying, but the killer objection is that I expect `Foo` to gain fields over time and I want that to be as frictionless as possible, so having to add a case to this function is annoying.
- I could write Template Haskell. I'm pretty sure this isn't too hard, but I tend to view TH as a last resort, so I'm hoping for something better.
- Could I use generics? I derived `Generic`, but when I tried to implement the `K1` case (specifically to handle `Rec0`) I couldn't figure out how to do it; I needed it to change the type.
- Is there a fourth option that I just missed?

If there is a generic way to write `mapFoo` without reaching for Template Haskell, I'd love to know about it! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `rank2classes` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes) [can derive this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.1.0.1/docs/Rank2-TH.html#v:deriveFunctor) for you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Rank2.TH (deriveFunctor)

data Foo f = Foo {fooInt :: f Int, fooBool :: f Bool}

$(deriveFunctor ''Foo)
```

Now you can write `mapFoo = Rank2.(<$>)`.

Comment: It turns out this didn't work in my actual use case because `rank2classes` doesn't support polykinded parameters, but your answer is still a good answer to the question as I asked it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Oh, I should be explicit that this is a *manual* method - it's a pointer to a package that has lots of useful functions and type classes but afaik no TH to generate what you want.  Pull requests welcome, I'm sure.

The [parameterized-utils package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-utils-1.0.0) provides a rich set of higher rank classes.  For your needs there's [FunctorF](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-utils-1.0.0/docs/Data-Parameterized-TraversableF.html#t:FunctorF):

```
-- | A parameterized type that is a function on all instances.
class FunctorF m where
  fmapF :: (forall x . f x -> g x) -> m f -> m g
```

And the instances are what you probably expect:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Data.Parameterized.TraversableF

data Foo f = Foo {fooInt :: f Int, fooBool :: f Bool}

instance FunctorF Foo where
  fmapF op (Foo a b) = Foo (op a) (op b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `GHC.Generics`-based implementation if you still prefer not to use `TemplateHaskell`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics

data Foo f = Foo {
    fooInt :: f Int,
    fooBool :: f Bool,
    fooString :: f String
    } deriving (Generic)


class Functor2 p q f where
    fmap2 :: (forall a. p a -> q a) -> f p -> f q

instance (Generic (f p), Generic (f q), GFunctor2 p q (Rep (f p)) (Rep (f q))) => Functor2 p q f where
    fmap2 f = to . (gfmap2 f) . from 

class GFunctor2 p q f g where
    gfmap2 :: (forall a. p a -> q a) -> f x -> g x

instance (GFunctor2 p q a b) => GFunctor2 p q (D1 m1 (C1 m2 a)) (D1 m1 (C1 m2 b)) where
    gfmap2 f (M1 (M1 a)) = M1 (M1 (gfmap2 f a))

instance (GFunctor2 p q a c, GFunctor2 p q b d) => GFunctor2 p q (a :*: b) (c :*: d) where
    gfmap2 f (a :*: b) = gfmap2 f a :*: gfmap2 f b

instance GFunctor2 p q (S1 m1 (Rec0 (p a))) (S1 m1 (Rec0 (q a))) where
   gfmap2 f (M1 (K1 g)) = M1 (K1 (f g))   


-- Tests
foo = Foo (Just 1) (Just True) (Just "foo")

test1 = fmap2 (\(Just a) -> [a]) foo   

test2 = fmap2 (\[a] -> Left "Oops") test1
```

I'm not sure though if it is possible to avoid `MultiParamTypeClasses` to make `class Functor2` identical to the one defined `rank2classes`.